# ruby on rails passing foreign key in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, foreign-keys, associations

Im trying to setup a simple environment:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Webpage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :content

  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :webpage
end
```

I am trying to setup an environment that when the 'show' method of a Webpage contains a 'create' form for a Micropost.

Initially, Microposts were only associated with Members - and this was working fine (the member_id is being set upon login as a cookie and that cookie is being stacked to the Micropost.build method).

The problem here is that I cannot pass the webpage_id - I have tried setting the webpage_id as a cookie and passing it, but that was no good.  And currently I am trying to pass the webpage_id as a hidden variable.

The controller for Micropost :create

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @micropost  = current_member.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    @webpage = Webpage.find(params['webpage_id'])
    @micropost.webpage = @webpage
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end
end
```

and the Webpage :show View:

```
<table class="front" summary="For signed-in members">
    <tr>
      <td class="main">
        <h1 class="micropost">What's up?</h1>
        <%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
          <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_area :content %>
            <input type="hidden" id="webpage_id" name="micropost[webpage_id]" value="<%= @webpage.id %>"/>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Everytime I submit the create form, I can see the webpage_id being passed but it is not being saved and the error I get is:

"Couldn't find Webpage without an ID"

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Cheers,

Damo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the microposts a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) of webpage in your routes.rb file.

This way you can make a form:

```
form_for([@webpage, Micropost.new]) do |f|
```

It will then POST to:

```
webpage_microposts POST   /webpage/:webpage_id/microcomments
```

And you will access the webpage id in your Micropost controller as such:

```
@webpage = Webpage.find(params[:webpage_id])
```

Comment: thanks mike - the issue I have now is that I am getting an error that the "build" method associated with the Member is not defined.  It is possible to pass one foreign key as a cookie and one as an association as you mentioned above?

Comment: Are you sure it's related to this answer? I didn't do anything to the model.

Comment: Never mind Mike - it turns out that I am a Rails beginner and blind :-P ... A type in the Microposts controller.  Thanks again for all of your help!!!